# Order set of data in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

My app retrieves some data from Core Data such as someones name, birthda, home adress etc.

My initial view calculates the distance between the persons, but how do i load in the distance ordered descending to a table view.

Maybe a dumb question but i was trying to achieve this using a NS Mutable dictionary but was unlucky I added keys and values to an nsmutable dictionary but couldnt load this into a table view. Any thoughts on how to get this working or what i should use instead of mutable dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can discern exactly what you're trying to accomplish, or what part of it is giving you trouble, but perhaps the `sortUsingComparator:^()` method of `NSMutableArray` could be of help.

Here's a naive example of using it to sort an `NSMutableArray` named `moviesOnly` by comparing the creation date of each element.

```
//Order by NSURLCreationDateKey
[moviesOnly sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSURL* a, NSURL* b){
    NSDate* a1 = [[a resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLCreationDateKey] error:nil] objectForKey:NSURLCreationDateKey];
    NSDate* b1 = [[b resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLCreationDateKey] error:nil] objectForKey:NSURLCreationDateKey];
    return [a1 compare:b1];
    }
 ];
```

Assuming you [can well-order all of your elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_ordered) then a comparator like this can put your NSMutableArray in order for you. Then you point your UITableViewDataSource protocol methods at your sorted NSMutableArray.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//point the relevant property of each cell at the corresponding member of your now sorted NSMutableArray here
}
```